# TapToPlace demo not works fine

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, hololens

I’m trying to use this “TapToPlace” scene demo that includes Unity "Holotoolkit" and seems that the project launchs fine in Hololens, but I can’t see any 3D model (as cube or cylinder). I can see the visual meshes of the mapping, but my “hologram” is not anywhere =(

Any idea to solve this?

I'm using all default code, I haven't done any changes.

Here's a screenshot of the Unity project:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Unity editor doesn't support spatial mapping. You have to use the Holographic Emulator feature that was introduced in Unity 5.5 so you can test the TapToPlace script properly.

Here's the [link](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/09/29/introducing-holographic-emulation/) to the blog on how you can use the Holographic Emulator of Unity.

You will be needing the following requirements as well:

1. You need Unity 5.5 installed in your machine
2. You have to have Windows 10 anniversary update (or later) installed

**Note**: Based on my experience, the Unity 5.5 beta 9 is the version in where Holographic Emulator works perfectly fine. Just an FYI in case you encounter some problems with testing the Holographic Emulator

Answer (score 0):

The Unity Emulator and HoloToolkit do support spatial mapping.  You can use the Object Surface Observer to simulate an environment inside the unity emulator.  Add the Object Surface Observer component to your scene (usually attached to the same gameobject as the spatial mapping observer).  Configure the Object Surface Observer with a saved mesh, which you can create yourself from the 3d view menu in the web portal on your device/emulator.

For a more detailed explanation check out this article on my blog: http://www.cameronvetter.com/2016/11/22/hololens-tutorial-object-surface-observer/